# fetching all related comments from all posts with adonisJs

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, orm, adonis.js

So i am trying to get all the posts in my database and join all related comments to those posts and return them, what basically translates too:

```js
const posts = await Posts.all()
const postsWithComments = posts.with('comments').fetch()

return response.json(postsWithComments)
```

the model for Posts has a function called comments, which returns a `hasMany` relationship.

The issue is that using it in on `all()` the posts will result in a `posts.with is not a function` error.

What will however work, is when fetching a **single** post from the database and returning all its related comments by doing

```js
const posts = await Posts.find(1)
```

Comment: The `fetch` method should at least contain parentheses `()`, like in [this example](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships#_basic_example). I'm trying to find in [the documentation of Adonis.js](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/routing) how the `Posts.all()` method works and what it returns, can you point it out for me? Otherwise check the value of `posts` after awaiting `Posts.all()`. It probably does not have the `with()` method.

Comment: the missing parentheses were a typo.
And i have looked around what that method does at well in the discord group, but all they tell me is that i need to do ``Posts.query().with('comments').fetch()`` and that I have to check the source code to see what those other methods do.

This does work, but 10 min later i run into a similar issue again, and without any explanation I will keep getting these errors

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the relation and the column name cannot be the same, Lucid will override the names.